# Exchange 2010 Recovery: Mailbox not found using Restore-Mailbox

Tags: exchange, restore, mailbox

Exchange 2010 SP1 Update Rollup 5 server information store database was restored to a Recovery Database using EMC Networker successfully. The Recovery Database is in a mounted state with mailboxes listed within in it.

- However, when restoring the mailbox content using the following command:

> Restore-Mailbox –Identity MYMAILBOX –RecoveryDatabase MYRECOVERYDB
>   –RecoveryMailbox LOSTMAILBOX –TargetFolder FOLDERFORLOSTMAILBOX

Returns the following error:

```
Mailbox "LOSTMAILBOX" doesn't exist on database "MYRECOVERYDB".
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Restore-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 66265C53,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.RestoreMailbox
```

*Note: I've used the correct alias name for the mailbox name; I've also tried combinations such as first name, or last name or both and so forth.*

- Issuing a `Get-MailboxStatistics -Database MYRECOVERYDB` to see if the mailbox is there and it is as shown below:

> ```
> DisplayName               ItemCount    StorageLimitStatus
>
> LOSTMAILBOX              39495           MailboxDisabled
> ```

*Note: The `StorageLimitStatus` shows a strange output of `MailboxDisabled`. Perhaps this may be the culprit.*

---

Going by the article's documentation I cannot complete the restore of the mailbox as I'm stuck at the restore-mailbox error that it cannot be found.

Please advise.

*Source of article: http://www.testlabs.se/blog/2012/07/05/exchange-2010-restore-to-recovery-database-using-emc-networker/*

Answer (score 1):

Note that for `Restore-Mailbox` you should be using the DisplayName as reported by

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Database MYRECOVERYDB
```

as the parameter to `-RecoveryMailbox`. If the DisplayName contains spaces, you have to enclose it in quote signs (`"Lost Mailbox"`).

The "MailboxDisabled" storage limit status should not prevent you from retrieving data off the mailbox, it just is a status set when mailbox storage limits are exceeded. If you are concerned by this, you should be able to change the limits by running `Set-Mailbox` with the `-ProhibitSendQuota` and `ProhibitReceiveQuota` parameters and waiting a bit (the information store caches this information and refreshes it every 2 hours, so it might take that long for your change to show).

Answer (score 0):

Will you able to see mailbox in the disconnect mailbox under the recipient configuration via the Exchange Management Console?
[image]

Now Run Clean-MailboxDatabase "Database Name" in the EMS and try again.

You can also refer following links:

https://techgenix.com/deleted-mailbox-items-exchange/

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/37235-recover-a-deleted-mailbox-in-exchange-2010